# React: Uncaught TypeError: tokenIds.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React to generate components from an array held in state via hooks. Initialized array is working without any problems, but it stops working after update of its state:

```
export function AiShip(props) {
    const shipType = props.shipType;
    const maxShields = Ships[shipType][Stats.shields];
    const maxHull = Ships[shipType][Stats.hull];
    const squadId = props.squadId;

    const [targetPosition, setTargetPosition] = useState([PSN.FARFRONT]);
    const [tokenIds, setTokenIds] = useState([3, 4]); //todo remove initial values

    function handleTokenIdChange(value, index) {
        const tTokenIds = tokenIds;
        tTokenIds.splice(index, 1, value);
        setTokenIds(...tTokenIds);
        };


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{Ships[props.shipType][Stats.name]}</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <ShipStats shipType={shipType}/>
                    <div className="row ">
                        <div className="col-4">
                            <h3>ID:</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-4">
                            <h3>Shields:</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-4">
                            <h3>Hull:</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {
                        tokenIds.map( (tokenId) =>
                             <ShipVariables key={tokenIds.indexOf(tokenId)} maxShields={maxShields} maxHull={maxHull}
                                           tokenIdIndex={tokenIds.indexOf(tokenId)}
                                           handleTokenIdChange={handleTokenIdChange}/>)
                    }
                    <br/>
```

State is updated via the handleTokenIdChange function. The resulting array is still an array (I checked that through the Array.isArray function). The code for triggering the state update is here:

```
<div className="col-4">
                    <Select options={idOptions} onChange={e => props.handleTokenIdChange(e.value, props.tokenIdIndex)}/>
                </div>
```

I know that typically the problem is that the variable is not an array but e.g. an object - but that doesn't seem to be the case here. The result is still an array storing a number. The select allows user to choose one of these values:

```
const idOptions = [
        {value: 0, label: 0},
        {value: 1, label: 1},
        {value: 2, label: 2},
        {value: 3, label: 3},
        {value: 4, label: 4},
        {value: 5, label: 5},
        {value: 6, label: 6},
        {value: 7, label: 7},
        {value: 8, label: 8},
        {value: 9, label: 9},
    ];
```

This is the error stack:

````
AiShip.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: tokenIds.map is not a function
    at AiShip (AiShip.js:49)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16260)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:18347)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20176)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25780)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24698)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24671)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24270)
    at react-dom.development.js:12199
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12194)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12182)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24423)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1438)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5881)
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here, in the `handleTokenIdChange` function:

```
setTokenIds(...tTokenIds);
```

`tTokenIds` is an array, but `...tTokenIds` isn't:

```
let myArray = [1,2,3]
console.log(...myArray) // 1 2 3
```

So you can't use `.map` on it.

### Solution

Given the context, I assume you were trying to use destructuring to create a copy of your array. Instead of doing `...tTokenIds`, you have to use `[...tTokenIds]`:

```
let myArray = [1,2,3]
console.log([...myArray]) // [1, 2, 3]
```

You can also use `Array.prototype.slice()` to create a copy of an array:

```
console.log(myArray.slice()) // [1, 2, 3]
```

### Important to know

Note that creating a copy of your state object *before* doing any modifications to it is a better practice:

```
function handleTokenIdChange(value, index) {
    const tTokenIds = [...tokenIds];
    tTokenIds.splice(index, 1, value);
    setTokenIds(tTokenIds);
}
```

Comment: That's interestingm thanks - but why does Array.isArray(tokenIds), called after the update, return true?

Could you suggest a proper way to update the array?

Comment: Does it return true after your use of the spread operator? I can't seem to reproduce that. In my example, `Array.isArray(...myArray)` returns `false`

Comment: Yes, it did:
 tTokenIds.splice(index, 1, value);
        setTokenIds([...tTokenIds]);
        console.log("New token ids: ");
        console.log(tokenIds);
        console.log("Is array: " + Array.isArray(tokenIds));

Returned true and the object in the console was an array, with updated values. But your modification worked as promised, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you spread the array via

```
setTokens(...tTokenIds)
```

Your state no longer becomes an array, each item is extracted as individual value during a spread. Therefore, it would most likely just result in the first item of the array becoming the state and the rest ignored, hence why `map` is no longer possible.

You need to spread the array into a new array i.e. `[...tTokenIds]`, or you could just use `tTokenIds.slice()` to clone the array.

*Please note that this will not clone the items already in the array, they will still be the same instances from the previous array*